# Jest SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run a very basic jest test but I am keep ing getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' . In my local the test case is working fine but when I run on gitlab ci I get the error. I am unable to figure out.

Below is my code.My application is on nestjs framework.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test api",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "start": "nest start",
    "test": "jest --verbose true",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.3.9",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.3.9",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.2.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.3.9",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.2.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.4",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.3.9",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.54.1",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "restoreMocks": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {
          "tsconfig": "tsconfig.test.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "incremental": true,
    "typeRoots": ["types", "node_modules/@types"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "scripts", "dist"]
}
```

gitlab.yml

```
node_modules:
  stage: build
  image: image
  artifacts:
    name: node_modules
    paths:
      - node_modules
  script:
    - rm -rf package-lock.json rm -rf node_modules npm install
  extends:
    - .defaults:test
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules


test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: '$DEPLOY_ONLY == "false"'
      when: always
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
  needs:
    - docker-image
    - node_modules
  extends:
    - .defaults:test
    - docker-image
```

test case class

```
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { AppController } from "app.controller";
import { AppService } from "app.service";

describe("AppController", () => {
  let appController: AppController;
  let appService: AppService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();

    appController = module.get<AppController>(AppController);
    appService = module.get<AppService>(AppService);
  });

  describe("getApp", () => {
    it("should call the get function from app controller", async () => {
      const result = "Hello World";
      jest.spyOn(appService, "getHello").mockImplementation(() => result);
      expect(await appController.getHello()).toEqual(result);
    });
  });
});
```

Error log on gitlab CI

```
/builds/qcx/qcx-app-store-api/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run.js:129
    if (error?.stack) {
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/qcx/qcx-app-store-api/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/index.js:18:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! package.json@1.0.0 test: `jest --verbose true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the package.json@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: The optional chaining operator `.?` was added in Node 14, so I'm wondering if you are using an older version of Node?

Comment: @Fenton I am using node version v18.15.0

Comment: Are you setting the Node version in GitLab, i.e. `image: node:latest` in your CI YAML file?

Answer (score 2):

The [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is available in Node.js since [version 14](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility). You are probably using an older version of Node.js

Switch to version 14 or, even better, to version 18 (because version 14 reaches its [end of life](https://github.com/nodejs/release#release-schedule) in about 6 weeks) and it should work.

Comment: How do you change Node versions using the Gitlab CI system?

Comment: @axiac Thank you for pointing this out. The issue is with the base docker image. That base docker image has old alpine with nodejs version 12.  I need to update latest version of alpine to make apk add --update nodejs to the current version